# UIView which is added as subview in UIWindow is not visible in the presented view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, addsubview, presentviewcontroller

I'm showing a UIView as subview in all view controllers using below function.

```
func showSubViewInAllScreens() {

    let mySubView = MySubView()

    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.last else { return }

    window.addSubview(mySubView)

}
```

But if I present a new view controller over my current visible view controller, then this subview is not visible in the presented view controller. The subview stays behind the presented view controller. Can anyone please provide a solution to show this subview over all view controllers which are going to be presented after the subview is displayed ?

We can use "window.bringSubviewToFront(mySubView)" to bring the subview over the presented view controller every time a view controller is being presented. But In my case, I can't detect when a view controller is going to be presented.

Comment: "I can't detect when a view controller is going to be presented" How can that be?

Comment: I'm developing a framework and this showSubViewInAllScreens() function is present inside that framework. From the framework, I can't detect when a view controller is going to be presented in the parent app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the [z position](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition) of `mySubView`'s layer.

Comment: I have another case now. I have one button in mySubView. Tap event of that button is not called, if mySubView is over the presented view. controller. If the presented view controller is dismissed, then the tap event of that button works fine. Can you please tell  how to fix this one ? Thanks.

Comment: If you have a different question, please ask it as another question by clicking the Ask Question button at the top right. Don't "leech" in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: I have asked this as another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75763710/16197930). If you know how to fix this one, please post your solution. Thanks.